# About uniform convergence and L^2 convergence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am reading the book Applied Analysis by John K. Hunter. And Lemma 7.8 states

> Suppose that $f\in H^k(T)$ for $k>1/2$. Let $$S_N(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f_n}e^{inx}$$ be the Nth partial sum of the Fourier series of f, and define $$||f^{(k)}|| = (\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|n|^{2k}|\hat{f_n}|^2)^{1/2}$$
>   Then there is a constant $C_k$, independent of $f$, such that 
>   $$||S_N-f||_{\infty} \leq \frac{C_k}{N^{k-1/2}}||f^{(k)}||$$
>   and $(S_N)$ converges uniformly to $f$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$

Here $H^k(T) = \{f\in L^2(T)|f(x) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{inx},\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|n|^{2k}|\hat{f_n}|^2<+\infty\}$ and $T = [0,2\pi]$.

My question is is this uniform convergence up tp a zero measure? If I change the value of $f$ on a zero measure set, the above is still true. But the value of $||S_N-f||_{\infty}$ will be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in H^{k}(T)$ then $f$ is actually continuous and the essential supremum is same as actual supremum: $\sum n^{2k}|c_n|^{2}<\infty$ implies $\sum|c_n| \leq (\sum n^{2k}|c_n|^{2})^{1/2}(\sum \frac 1 {n^{2k}})^{1/2}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {n^{2k}}<\infty$. But $\sum |c_n| <\infty$ implies that the series $\sum c_ne^{inx}$ conveges uniformly, so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: $\sum c_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly to some $\tilde{f}$ in $C(T)$, but $\sum c_n e^{inx}$ converges to f in $L^2(T)$. So how can you conclude f is continuous from $\sum c_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @J.Li $L^{2}$ convergence implies almost everywhere convergence for  a subsequnce. So, if a sequence of continuous functions converges in $L^{2}$ as well as uniformly then the limits are the same and the $L^{2}$ limit is equal a.e. to a continuous function.

Comment: Yeah, so the convergence is up to a zero measure set. And if f is also continuous, then $\sum c_n e^{inx}$ converges uniformly to f in $C(T)$. Am I correct?

Comment: @J.Li Yes, that is right.